# How to feed multiple outputs of previous layer to a successive lstm layer

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I've just started using Keras. I encountered a problem that how to feed multiple outputs of previous layers to a successive lstm layer. My model(part) is just like below:

```
batch_size = 64

output_1 = Dense(output_dim=(128, ), input_dim=(200, ))

output_2 = Dense(output_dim=(128,), input_dim=(200, ))

output_3 = Dense(output_dim=(128,), input_dim=(200, ))

output_4 = Dense(output_dim=(128,), input_dim=(200, ))
```

Now my problem is  how to feed all above outputs to a lstm ? the input_dim should be like **(batch_size, number_of_previous_outputs, 128)**

Comment: Are you still interested in this question? Because I think I found the solution?

Comment: @ Marcin Możejko sorry for late reply. I have changed my neural network structure. But I am still interested in your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a merge layer (https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#the-merge-layer). Either with concat or with sum to and then feed the merge layer into the lstm.

code example:

```
merged_output = merge([output_1, output_2, output_3, output_4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
lstm = LSTM(...)(merged_output)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am confused about the shape of your merged_output layer . The shape of output_1 is (batch_size, output_dim),and I need the shape of merged_output to be (batch_size, number_of_previous_output, output_dim) . @Thomas Pinetz

Comment: You can add a reshape layer to accomplish your desired output. https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape